# How to create a New Column in Pandas on if else condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe. I want to create a new column named `mpg_high`

[image]

The condition of the column is:
`mpg_high = 1` if `mpg > average mpg` (this is the mean of mpg where I placed `np.mean(df.mpg) else = 0`.

I tried various methods but kept getting syntax errors. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['mpg_high'] = np.where(df.mpg > np.mean(df.mpg), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be reduced to straight binary comparison and conversion to **int**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"mgp":np.random.randint(15,35, 50)})

df["mgp_high"] = df["mgp"].gt(df["mgp"].mean()).astype(int)
```